# Sending status codes in PHP does not work as expected

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to check if a username is available for registering by doing async validation with AngularJS on the client side and PHP on the server side.

So I do something simple like this to check if the user exists:

```
$user = User::find_by('username', $_GET['username']);
if ($user) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");       
}
```

and I try to return some status codes if it finds the user or not.

But when I try to use something like postman to send GET requests the returning status code is always 200. It doesn't look like I'm able to send different status codes at all.

Comment: so what is $user being set to?

Comment: header() is only valid before php creating any output. Did you check that?

Comment: You'd generally return data, for instance JSON, that has a property that indicates if the user was found or not, I don't think it's a good idea to trigger the ajax error handler by returning a 404.

Comment: User::find_by('username', $_GET['username']); is returning true/false? can you paste a var_dump($user) ?

Comment: I have checked both occurances even if the User is found or not by "echoing" inside those conditionals. Also I have removed everything from the page and to just return a 404, still I get 200.

Comment: As @Shiji.Jiang said, maybe you are sending something to the output before setting the header. Set logging report to warning level and check if you are not getting this warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, select the network tab then see what headers (if any) are actually being sent.  And use: header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK",true,200); http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php